# In blueprintjs, how to set `accept` attribute in a FileInput

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, blueprintjs

Could not figure out how to set the `accept` attribute when using react-blueprintjs. For reference, in HTML this would just be

```
<input type='file' accept='.txt,.csv,...' />
```

I tried using `inputProps={accept: '...'}` but this results in a "Cannot find name..." error.

Sorry if this is a n00b question, this is sitting right at React/blueprint/HTML/typescript blind spot for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a react question. See the docs on [specifying attributes with JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx). Namely, expressions need to be wrapped in curly braces:

```
<FileInput inputProps={{accept: "..."}} />
```